# Heroku addon and dashboard customization

Tags: heroku

I saw that some Heroku addons are adding information to the Heroku dashboard (e.g. Logging addons show a graphical view of the logs, monitoring addons show nice graphical pie-charts).

Could anyone please point me to some reference, as to how to achieve this with my own Addon which i'm currently writing?
I used the basic tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-heroku-add-on) but it doesn't mention anything about dashboard interation

thanks